What is the U.N. Report on Children and Armed Conflict and how does it affect Israel which was recently added?
According to the Times Of Israel, the UN has added Israel to the ‘list of shame’ for alleged rights violations against children during war. The article claims that the 'list' is attached to an annual report submitted by Secretary-General Antonio Guterres’s office that documents rights violations against children in armed conflict.
Why does the U.N. maintain the so-called ‘list of shame’ and how does it affect entities that are added to it, particularly how does it affect Israel which was recently added?
Note: I'm aware that the article from the Times of Israel states that Hamas is added to the list along-side Israel but Hamas is a small group compared to Israel which is a state.

As a first approximation, if any organ of the UN does anything other than persuade a bunch of countries to sign a treaty, and that organ is not the UNSC, it probably has no effect at all (other than symbolism/politics/etc.).

@Kevin It's not the like the UNSC resolutions immediately change facts on the ground either. That's just the way diplomacy and international law work.

@Relaxed: Sure, but the UNSC's decisions at least have the possibility of maybe eventually having a nonzero number of UN peacekeepers show up at the location of controversy.

The UN General Assembly requires the UN Secretary General to provide an annual report on Children and Armed Conflict to the UN Security Council and others. The next one is due in a couple of weeks and the UN informed the Israeli ambassador that Israel will be in it.

Calling it a 'list of shame' or 'blacklist' is inaccurate use by media who think that the formal name won't be suitable for their headlines.
The effect will be that the international community, including the UNSC, puts a spotlight on the situation of children in that conflict and talks about it.


Are you saying that the term "list of shame" is purely clickbait, and politicians don't use that term (or something similar) among themselves?

@Barmar, I'm not in their informal, off-the-record meetings. But I strongly suspect that world leaders would use a more precise term. The UN produces lists of DPRK sanctions violators, money laundering countries, greenhouse gas emitters, etc. Calling any of those 'list of shame' without more context is pointless. But the term clickbait refers to cryptic headlines with the purpose of generating clicks, some media use of 'list of shame' is meant as characterization rather than concealment.

You'd think so, wouldn't you? I'd also expect them to avoid loaded terms like "witch hunt", yet they don't. World leaders are people, too, and they have agendas.

@Barmar, using terms like 'witch hunt' or 'list of shame' either needs to come with context, or someone has to spend a lot of screen time to link it with a specific context in the public mind. Otherwise the public goes 'what are you talking about?'

Who says there's no context? The article says it's attached to the report on rights violations. That's the context.

@Barmar, now you are talking about media again. My point: If an ambassador calls the government, "we'll be on the UN list of shame," I'd expect the government to reply with "which one, make a proper report" ...

I'm thinking of an official saying something like "I received the UN report, and I see that Israel is now on its 'list of shame'."

As an analogy, the US government has a Terrorist Screening Database, but they often refer to it using the more informal term "terrorist watchlist". I'm sure there are many other similar informal names for official documents (I suspected "no fly list" was one, but it's apparently the official name).

@Barmar, that informal name is sufficiently specific to come into everyday use. Just as "jurisdictions of primary concern" is associated with money laundering.

It depends ...
if the country to be added to the list is backed by, say, the US, then maybe no serious global effect is expectable offically, at least among the Westerners which control the main global media and misuse their power to control world-wide institutes as far as they could, and hence the effects are limited probably to regular people who mainly can vote for other officials in future, and limited to politically independent countries which can use the  situations to manifest the Westerners' hypocrisy/double standards.
But if the country to be listed is not backed by the US and its Westerners allies, probably withstanding them, things can differ magnificently, as they often use any possible excuse to bit their enemies, organizing the whole community around a good concept against their enemies, like they usually misuse human-right concept. Sometimes a single woman dies in a doubtful manner and virtually every known and unknown Westerner politician react and a flow of anger/hate is conducted to smear the face of their enemies globally, and this affect that enemy in several aspects; on the other hand, sometimes thousands of kids/women are killed with no doubt about them being killed out of oppression and virtually no one care and even any flow of objection is condemned again virtually by all such politicians.
Therefore, it can have effect and indeed has effect, but the quality/quantity varies over likes/dislikes, and capabilities individuals/officials have to affect as much as they could. Consider it as a News/excuse that is declared/confirmed by a usually assumed accurate source. Those who like the News will try to promote it and use it for their interests, and those who dislike it try to withstand it, either ignore it and request for everyone to ignore it, or to misinterpret it, or suspect in the authenticity of the source. How different sides benefit/withstand a News is itself a kind of war ...

Update. In case a reader will assume this answer not addressing the specific question asked, the question has three parts:

"Why does the U.N. maintain the ... list"(?)
and "how does it affect entities that are added to it"(?)
and "particularly how does it affect Israel which was recently added?",

and a general answer is tried to be given here, no claim for it to be comprehensive at all, which anyway can also be restricted on Israel particularly as it is heavily supported by the US and other Westerners. The News that says Hamas is also added to the same list, although the questioner is not interested in, again follows the same rule. But why Israel is bolded here, might be due to previous propaganda by Westerners, that Israel is so good and Hamas is so bad, so that the recent News now seems to be an inflection point about Israel but not Hamas in the eyes of many audiences. Hamas has always been condemned, but Israel was always glorified even more than God is glorified, so much that people can object against God easier than objecting against a group of people who was once chosen by God! Therefore, so strongly that Israel is supported by the US and other Westerners, "then maybe no serious global effect is expectable offically, at least among the Westerners which control the main global media and misuse their power to control world-wide institutes as far as they could, and hence the effects are limited probably to regular people who mainly can vote for other officials in future, and limited to politically independent countries which can use the  situations to manifest the Westerners' hypocrisy/double standards"

The question is specifically about how Israel will be affected. Your answer doesn't mention Israel by name once, and instead tries to discuss the general case without addressing any of the specifics of Israel's situation.

@F1Krazy, updated my answer to be more specific about your point

Please back your answers with some references.

@sfxedit, consider "The Hague Invasion Ac" as one example. What Westerners did about deah of Mahsa Amini (Note: the wiki page is full of lies, and you can hopefully guess why) is another one.

Also look what Western media/politician do if an Iranian policeman hits someone that would be disqualification of the whole Iranian government, or if someone kills a number of persons that would be interpreted as Iran being in lack of security, but then you see in News what US policemen and gangs do and guess what are the reactions ...
